# InvalidParameterException or IllegalArgumentException

Tags: c#, java, exception

In Java when should you throw `IllegalArgumentException` and when `InvalidParameterException`?
Coming from a C# background we would have an `ArgumentNullException` that derived from `ArgumentException`. If I would want to implement a equivalent `ArgumentNullException`/`ParameterNullException` in Java should I extend `IllegalArgumentException` or `InvalidParameterException`?

Note: I'm not trying to implement a `ArgumentNullException`/`ParameterNullException` this would just provide me with a better understanding if I could match up these with the C# framework.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's no apparent need to subclass those exceptions, I'd use them right away to signal, that a method has been called with illegal arguments. I'd always describe the real cause in the exceptions message part.

`java.security.InvalidParameterException` is already a subclass of `IllegalArgumentException` *designed for use by the JCA/JCE engine classes* (JavaDoc) and I wouldn't use or subclass it in a different context.

Comment: But when will you throw `InvalidParameterException` rather than `IllegalArgumentException` ?

Comment: @Cornelius, probably never :-)

Comment: @Cornelius - I'd use this special `InvalidParameterException` **only** if I had to implement interfaces or subclass types from the *Java Crypto Architecture* framework and throwing of this exception is mandatory (what I usually leave to the experts ;-) )

Comment: @Andreas_D My confusion with is the term 'illegal' which has unfortunate emotional loading, we don't want to punish the caller, just tell them that what they have asked us to do doesn't make sense. Naming thing is *really* hard, no computer language is perfect etc.

Answer (score 20):

First thanks for your question. Now I know about existence of `InvalidParameterException`. This exception belongs to package java.security and according to its javadoc

```
 * This exception, designed for use by the JCA/JCE engine classes, 
 * is thrown when an invalid parameter is passed 
 * to a method.
```

IllegalArgumentException belongs to java.lang and therefore can be used for any purpose.

I believe that in 99.9% of cases you should use IllegalArgumentException and use InvalidParameterException only in security context.

Comment: Nice, I think `InvalidParameterException` is miss named, the name is too general, people probably will not notice the fact that it shouldn't be used in normal cases. In IDE it's not easy to notice the class is from a different package, they are auto imported usually.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the `java.lang` makes it clear which one to use! :)

Answer (score 5):

There is already an exception to throw when you expect parameters to not be null: NullPointerException. Some programmers thinks that only faulty code throws NullPointerException, but if you really expect the parameters to not be null, and you can't recover from this situation, that's the right exception to throw. From the JavaDoc:

> Thrown when an application attempts to use null in a case where an object is required.

But if we are not talking about null values, but just an invalid value, then you should throw IllegalArgumentException. From the JavaDoc:

> Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or inappropriate argument.

As a general suggestion, I would say that you should get familiar with the Java exceptions (from java.lang package), and use them appropriately. If you don't find a suitable exception, then extend one.

Also note that the exception "InvalidParameterException" is in the package "java.security", which is probably *not* what you want.